# How to make a function for match character in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Special Letters:

```
N="TAG"
K="L"
D="E"

g4 = 'NKXD'
```

X can be anything, we want if N is not then check for T, A, G or if K is not then check for L or if D is not then check for E.

our special character is for N == `N, T, A, G` and for `K == K, Q` and for `D == D, E` but if N is there in this case there is no mismatch. I want only two special letter mismatch data or no mismatched like `NKXD` X can be anything.

`TKTL - here T, is special mismatch but L is mismatch I don't need, I want only two special mismatch data and NKXD X can be anything. these two condition I want in g4_match function.`

**Example:**

TLKD here T and L is the special mismatch and ALRD here A and L is special mismatch and TKJE - here T and E is special mismatch and NKID this type data here no mismatch or no special mismatch,

**Function**

```
def g4_match(X,Y):
N="TAG"
K="QL"
D="E"
spl_mismatch = 0
for x,y in zip(X,Y):
    #print x, y
    if x == 'N' and y in N:
        if x == 'K' and y in K:
            spl_mismatch += 1
        elif x == 'D' and y in D:
            spl_mismatch += 1  
    else:
        False
if spl_mismatch > 2:
    return False
return True
```

Input:

```
  X    Y
 NKXD RKAC
 NKXD KACT
 NKXD ACTI
```

I want to match the letter like N == R, K == K, X == A, D == C. Condition is `NKXD` is the main  in the place of `N can be T, A, G,` and `K == L` and `D == E` but at a time only two special mismatch allow example: `TLXD` here T and L is special mismatch letter.

**My Full Script**

```
import csv

def g4_match(X,Y):
    N="TAG"
    K="QL"
    D="E"
    dummylist=[]
    spl_match = 0
    for (i,j) in zip(X,Y):
    #print i, j
    if i=='N':
        if j == 'N':
            continue
        elif j in N:
            spl_match += 1
            dummylist.append((i,j))

    elif (i=='K'):
        if (j == 'K'):
            continue
        elif j in K:
            spl_match += 1
            dummylist.append((i,j))
    elif (i == 'D'):
        if(j == 'D'):
            continue
        elif j in D:
            spl_match += 1
            dummylist.append((i,j))
    elif (i=='X'):
        if(j=='X'):
            continue
        else:
            spl_match += 1
            dummylist.append((i,j)) 
   def match(X,Y):
        mismatch = 0
        for x,y in zip(X,Y):
            if not (x == 'X' or x == y):
                mismatch += 1


if mismatch > 1:
    return False
return True


def mean(arr):
    return (max(arr) + min(arr))/2
def H(protein,g1,g3,g4,g5):

    def find_matches(x,g4_match):
        match_positions = []
        matches         = []
        for i in range(len(protein) - len(x)):
            candidate = protein[i : i + len(x)]
            if match(x, candidate):
                match_positions.append(i)
                matches        .append(candidate)
            elif g4_match(x, candidate):
                match_positions.append(i)
                matches        .append(candidate)
        print("Mmatches: ",matches, match_positions)        
        return matches, match_positions

    L1, pL1 = find_matches(g1, match)
    L2, pL2 = find_matches(g3, match)
    L3, pL3 = find_matches(g4, g4_match)
    L4, pL4 = find_matches(g5, match)

    candidates = []
    for a in zip(pL1, L1):
        for b in zip(pL2, L2):
            for c in zip(pL3, L3):
                for d in zip(pL4, L4):
                    if (40 <= b[0] - a[0] <= 80 and
                        40 <= c[0] - b[0] <= 80 and
                        20 <= d[0] - c[0] <= 80    ):
                        print(a,b,c,d)
                        candidates.append((a,b,c,d))
                    elif (80 <= b[0] - a[0] <= 120 and
                          40 <= c[0] - b[0] <= 80 and 
                          120 <= d[0] - c[0] <= 180 ):
                        print(a,b,c,d)
                        candidates.append((a,b,c,d))
                    elif (40 <= b[0] - a[0] <= 80 and
                          80 <= c[0] - b[0] <= 80 and 
                          120 <= d[0] - c[0] <= 180 ):
                        print(a,b,c,d)
                        candidates.append((a,b,c,d))
    with open('output_test_1.csv', 'a') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        #wr.writerow([pdb_id])
        #wr.writerow([protein_name])
        wr.writerow([protein])
        #wr.writerow([source])
        for i in candidates: 
            wr.writerow([i])
    return candidates


g1 = 'GXXXXGK'
g3 = 'DXXG'
g4 = 'NKXD'
g5 = 'EXSAX'


protein = 'MASEIHMTGPMCLIENTNGRLMANPEALKILSAITQPMVVVAIVGLYRTGKSYLMNKLAGKKKGFSLGSTVQSHTKGIWMWCVPHPKKPGHILVLLDTEGLGDVEKGDNQNDSWIFALAVLLSSTFVYNSIGTINQQAMDQLYYVTELTHRIRSKSSPDENENEVEDSADFVSFFPDFVWTLRDFSLDLEADGQPLTPDEYLTYSLKLKKGTSQKDETFNLPRLCIRKFFPKKKCFVFDRPVHRRKLAQLEKLQDEELDPEFVQQVADFCSYIFSNSKTKTLSGGIQVNGPRLESLVLTYVNAISSGDLPCMENAVLALAQIENSAAVQKAIAHYEQQMGQKVQLPTETLQELLDLHRDSEREAIEVFIRSSFKDVDHLFQKELAAQLEKKRDDFCKQNQEASSDRCSALLQVIFSPLEEEVKAGIYSKPGGYRLFVQKLQDLKKKYYEEPRKGIQAEEILQTYLKSKESMTDAILQTDQTLTEKEKEIEVERVKAESAQASAKMLQEMQRKNEQMMEQKERSYQEHLKQLTEKMENDRVQLLKEQERTLALKLQEQEQLLKEGFQKESRIMKNEIQDLQTKMRRRKACTIS'
H(protein,g1,g3,g4,g5)
```

**output getting**

```
((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (126, 'VYNS'), (165, 'EDSAD'))

((44, 'GLYRTGK'), (86, 'KKPG'), (127, 'YNSI'), (165, 'EDSAD'))
.
.
.
.
((284, 'GIQVNGP'), (358, 'DSER'), (438, 'KLQD'), (499, 'QASAK'))
```

Its a big output file but I have entered first three line and last line. 
for example: `KLQD` is the last line third column, here I want my special letter match at a time only two letter allowed.

Comment: Why there are two arguments for function ?

Comment: which argument dear ?

Comment: (x,y) what are you passing to function and what is that expected ? description is not clear enough

Comment: I have edited please check my question above input

Comment: and what is the output ? You are passing  `X Y NKXD RKAC NKXD KACT NKXD ACTI` as input to function ? What is Y by the way ? Can you considerrephrase your question ?

Comment: @Sandeep Lade, I have edited my question again, please check

Comment: @Sandeep Lade, Please suggest me something to solve this problem

Comment: if i give `match('NKXD','RKAC')` for those strings `N!=R`( since R is not in TAF its not match),`K=K`(match),`X=A`( since X can be any character match),`D!=C` (since C is not in E ,not match), since only 2 matches are there return value is false . Is it correct ?

Comment: `NKXD` or `TLXD` or `TKXE` `X` can be anything. I want like that data, if NKXD is True, TLXD is True, TKXE is True but `TKXD` here only one special mismatch T.

Comment: Check and provide feedback for my answer. Will change if something needs to be

Comment: @Sandeep Lade, I have edited my full script, please check, I am not getting expected result dear

Comment: Sorry but please don't change the question. What are you expecting when you enter for the following inputs ?`match('NKXD','RKAC') `,`match('NKXD','KACT')`,`match('NKXD','ACTI')`,`match('NKXD','TQAK')`

Comment: Deat question is same, I am using your function for my script. I am trying for same. you can check it bro

Comment: can you answer my question ? What are you expecting when you enter for the following inputs ?match('NKXD','RKAC') ,match('NKXD','KACT'),match('NKXD','ACTI'),match('NKXD','TQA‌​K') ? Are you getting the expected output with my code ?

Comment: Dear, I want to match X with Y, X character is `NKXD` is default for all. but Y  letters are changing, here I want only special letters mismatch, N == TAG, K == LQ, D == E but at a time only two special mismatch allowed.

Comment: in the position of `X` can be any letter are allowed.

Comment: Why are you calling it as Special letter mismatch ? You are saying mismatch and you are using `N == TAG, K == LQ, D == E` . You should call it as special match ?

Comment: OK dear, I can call special match, please check once my full script

Comment: please join chatroom

Comment: Sorry bro, I can not because I am new user, they are not allowing me for chatroom

Answer (score 0):

Check this

**CODE**

```
def match(X,Y):
    N="TAG"
    K="QL"
    D="E"
    dummylist=[]
    spl_match = 0
    for (i,j) in zip(X,Y):
        #print i, j
        if i=='N':
            if j == 'N':
                continue
            elif j in N:
                spl_match += 1
                dummylist.append((i,j))

        elif (i=='K'):
            if (j == 'K'):
                continue
            elif j in K:
                spl_match += 1
                dummylist.append((i,j))
        elif (i == 'D'):
            if(j == 'D'):
                continue
            elif j in D:
                spl_match += 1
                dummylist.append((i,j))
        elif (i=='X'):
            if(j=='X'):
                continue
            else:
                spl_match += 1
                dummylist.append((i,j))
    print "Given string",X,Y
    print "Special matched elements",dummylist
    print "No of Special Matches",spl_match

    if spl_match > 2:

        return False
    else:
        return True
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 >>> match('NKXD','RKAC')
    Given string NKXD RKAC
    Special matched elements [('X', 'A')]
    No of Special Matches 1
    True
    >>> match('NKXD','KACT')
    Given string NKXD KACT
    Special matched elements [('X', 'C')]
    No of Special Matches 1
    True
    >>> match('NKXD','ACTI')
    Given string NKXD ACTI
    Special matched elements [('N', 'A'), ('X', 'T')]
    No of Special Matches 2
    True
    >>> 
>>> match('NKXD','TQAK')
Given string NKXD TQAK
Special matched elements [('N', 'T'), ('K', 'Q'), ('X', 'A')]
No of Special Matches 3
False
>>>
```

Comment: If input is this `X = 'NKXD','NKXD','NKXD', 'NKXD','NKXD', Y = 'TKPD','TLPD','NKXD', 'AKSE', 'GQWD'` then what will be output? please let me know

Comment: @user8866270 : Question is asked by you. You should tell what you are expecting . You should be precise enough to tell whether your input is a string or a list or something else . Also you should tell the output is boolean or something else . Sorry to say you were never clear in your requirement. I can't help any more

Comment: Sorry bro but can you please check once my full script? my others script is working fine but function g4_match is special mismatch function is not giving expected result.

Comment: I suggest to raise new question by posting what is required elaborately . If you want forum to check full code you should provide it while posting the question and should elaborate where is the problem .

Comment: Dear, Not able to ask new question now due to limit, if possible please check once, problem is in `g4_match` function  want to match the special character. as per example

Comment: What is the input you are giving to that function inside the script ? What is expected output  and what is actual output ?

Comment: Dear, I have edited my output, full script and expected output description, please check

Comment: can you please help ?